# Deleting rows between multiple sets of time stamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has time stamps in the form of (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss). I'm trying to delete data between two different time stamps. At the moment I can delete the data between 1 range of time stamps but I have trouble extending this to multiple time stamps.

For example, with the DataFrame I can delete a range of rows (e.g. 2015-03-01 00:20:00 to 2015-08-01 01:10:00) however, I'm not sure how to go about deleting another range alongside it. The code that does that is shown below.

```
index_list= df.timestamp[(df.timestamp >= "2015-07-01 00:00:00") & (df.timestamp <= "2015-12-30 23:50:00")].index.tolist()

df1.drop(df1.index[index_list1, inplace = True)
```

The DataFrame extends over 3 years and has every day in the 3 years included.
I'm trying to delete all the rows from months July to December (2015-07-01 00:00:00 to 2015-12-30 23:50:00) for all 3 years.

I was thinking that I create a helper column that gets the Month from the Date column and then drops based off the Month from the helper column.

I would greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Edit:
I've added in a small summarised version of the DataFrame. This is what the intial DataFrame looks like.

```
df    Date                   v
    2015-01-01 00:00:00     30.0
    2015-02-01 00:10:00     55.0
    2015-03-01 00:20:00     36.0
    2015-04-01 00:30:00     65.0
    2015-05-01 00:40:00     35.0
    2015-06-01 00:50:00     22.0
    2015-07-01 01:00:00     74.0
    2015-08-01 01:10:00     54.0
    2015-09-01 01:20:00     86.0
    2015-10-01 01:30:00     91.0
    2015-11-01 01:40:00     65.0
    2015-12-01 01:50:00     35.0
```

To get something like this

```
df    Date                   v
    2015-01-01 00:00:00     30.0
    2015-02-01 00:10:00     55.0
    2015-03-01 00:20:00     36.0
    2015-05-01 00:40:00     35.0
    2015-06-01 00:50:00     22.0
    2015-11-01 01:40:00     65.0
    2015-12-01 01:50:00     35.0
```

Where time stamps "2015-07-01 00:20:00 to 2015-10-01 00:30:00"and "2015-07-01 01:00:00 to 2015-10-01 01:30:00" are removed. Sorry if my formatting isn't up to standard.

Comment: When you post a question, please make sure to also add a sample input with expected output. This makes it easier to understand for the rest of us.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it in right now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my solution. You need to convert to the right data type and then use a simple operation, as detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you hinted, data manipulation is always easier when you use the right data types. To support time stamps, pandas has the [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) type. You can do this as follows:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  # No date format needs to be specified,
                                         # "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" is the standard
```

Then, removing all entries in the months of July to December for all years is straightforward:

```
df = df[df['Date'].dt.month < 7]  # Keep only months less than July
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for explaining the Timestamp type as well, was unaware of it's existence. Thank you again!

Comment: Not flexible enough as a solution. What if OP wants to remove non-continuous/non-contiguous months?

Answer (score 3):

If your timestamp column uses the correct dtype, you can just do:

`df.loc[df.timestamp.dt.month.isin([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 12])]`

This should filter out the months not inside the list.

Comment: OP wants to remove July-December. The above will give wrong results.

Comment: @crazyGamer Downvote, really? That's not even really a problem. OP can edit the list anyway.

Comment: I was getting a "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" when I tried running this :(

Comment: @577e94982d620b84f7c536d5e76f1e Fixed.

Comment: Works now as well, thanks! Just had to convert the DataType.